# How to add a payment method to Google Pay programmatically?

Tags: java, android, payment, android-pay, google-pay

I am working on an Android app that needs to be able to add a payment method to Google Pay. This feature is available for Apple Pay on iOS through [PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkaddpaymentpassrequestconfiguration). Is there an Android equivalent?

Comment: Are you trying to add a card that is owned by your app? Are you the card issuer? If so, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257989/how-to-add-credit-card-to-google-pay-from-my-app/57829311#57829311